# Access deeper levels of data from $scope retrieved from $http request in HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, angularjs-scope

I am having trouble accessing data stored in `$scope` from my view. Here's the setup:

I have image data stored in `data/images.json`.

```
{
  "sample-image": {
    "url": "imgs/sample.jpg",
    "description": "This is an image."
  }
}
```

It is accessed by an `$http` request in a factory,

```
app.factory('getImageData', ['$http', function($http) {
  var url = 'data/images.json';

  return $http.get(url)
  .success(function(data) {return data;})
  .error(function(err) {return err;});
}]);
```

That is called by the controller

```
app.controller('ImageCtrl', ['$scope', 'getImageData', function($scope, getImageData) {
    getImageData.then(function(data) {
      $scope.images = data;
    }, function(err) {
      console.warn('Error loading image: ', err);
    });
}]);
```

In my template I'd ideally like to have something like `<img src='{{ images.data.sample-image.url }} />`, however, `{{ images.data.sample-image.url }}` turns into `0`.

Please see the following template-result combos:

`<pre>{{ images.data }}</pre>` returns

```
{"sample-image":{"url":"imgs/sample.jpg","description":"This is an image."}}
```

However, `<pre>{{ images.data.sample-image }}</pre>` and `<pre>{{ images.data.sample-image }}` both return `0`

I can access the deeper levels of the data when I use an Angular function such as `ng-repeat`:

`<pre ng-repeat='image in images.data'>image.url</pre>` returns

```
imgs/sample.jpg
```

Why am I getting `0` when I call `{{ images.data.sample-image.url }}` if the data is clearly there and accessible?

Comment: How is `images.data` showing the requested json object?  When you set `$scope.images` to be the value of the `data` returned from your service, shouldn't `$scope.images['sample-image'].url` be what you want?  How does the data you returned get a 'data' property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is using the dash in the template, but you can access to the object attributes using it like this.

```
["sample-image"]
{{images[0].data["sample-image"].url}}
```

Example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dyYQOc6I8mVtbaU5IlCo?p=preview

I hope it helps,

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ng-src instead of interpolating image sources with `<img-src="{{...}}"/>` directly? See [Angular ng-src documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a dash? 'sample-image'

Shouldn't you be using an underscore?

Like: 'sample_image' because js will see this and evaluate ot like Mathematical equation.

You should try using string notation like images.data["sample-image"] instead
Let me know if this helps